# How do I trigger Alexa from an external software?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

This is probably the opposite of what people usually want to do.

Is it possible to write a piece of software that triggers Alexa?

Basically, like saying "Alexa, do something" to your Amazon Echo, but with code instead of talking. Perhaps by leveraging some Lambda function.

Comment: is it like you want Alexa to speak a response without a user speech?

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is try, think about security issues that would open up if you could do what you wanted...

https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/bda9d70c-2f0d-454d-9939-2eb82868cf35/announcing-contact-and-motion-sensor-apis-and-integration-into-alexa-routines-adding-new-home-automation-features-for-customers-and-new-opportunities-for-smart-home-developers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good option if you're just doing automation for personal use. This won't fly with consumer skills: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/40799/workaround-for-push-notifications.html